# How to read cycling and running data from Google Fit History API using readDailyTotal

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm trying to read daily data from Fitness History Api with method `readDailyTotal`. I want to read steps, cycling and running. I have implemented steps successfully but i can't get daily result for cycling and running.

This is code which i'm using to get steps and it works:

```
PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> resultSteps
                = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mGoogleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

resultSteps.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DailyTotalResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(@NonNull DailyTotalResult dailyTotalResult) {
          if (dailyTotalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet dataSet = dailyTotalResult.getTotal();

             for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "DataType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                            " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Field: " + field.getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Field: " + field.getFormat());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Field: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "---------------------------------");
                }
              }
          } 
      }
});
```

I tried to use same code but for cycling:

```
PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> resultCycling
                    = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mGoogleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_CYCLING_WHEEL_RPM);
```

also i tried to use different DataType like:
`TYPE_CYCLING_PEDALING_CADENCE`, `TYPE_CYCLING_PEDALING_CUMULATIVE`, `TYPE_CYCLING_WHEEL_REVOLUTION`

and it doesn't work. I read whole Fitness Fit documentation as well, and i didn't get how to do that.

So, my question is how to get daily data for cycling and running? And if you could give me some snippet for that, i would be grateful.

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you expecting the cycling data to be captured?  The standard FIT app will not gather this data I don't think it has any direct support for speed and cadence sensors which would be needed for this data.  There are 3rd party apps that may gather this data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about cycle pedaling data, but you can get a biking type data like this:

```
      DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(client, readRequest);

    DataReadResult dataReadResult = pendingResult.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved results: " + dataReadResult);
    if (dataReadResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {

            for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {

                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                Log.d(TAG, "getFitHistoryByTime: Activity " + bucket.getActivity());
                Log.d(TAG, "getFitHistoryByTime: Start - End  "
                        + dateFormat.format(bucket.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                        + " - "
                        + dateFormat.format(bucket.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {

                         if (dp.getDataType().equals(DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)) {
                            boolean activityToAdd = false;
                            ActivitiesData activitiesData = new ActivitiesData();
                            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                if (Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY.equals(field)) {
                                    int activityType = dp.getValue(field).asInt();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "getFitHistoryByTime: activity type " + activityType);
                                    if (FitnessActivities.getName(activityType).equals("biking")) {
                                        activityToAdd = true;
                                        Log.d(TAG, "getFitHistoryByTime: added activity: " + FitnessActivities.getName(activityType));

                                    }
                                }

                                if (Field.FIELD_DURATION.equals(field)) {
                                    long duration = dp.getValue(field).asInt();  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            .....
```

Perhaps you get the idea based on this code snippet.
Also, try to post this question on Google Fit [G+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103314459667402704958).

Kind regards.
MB